# librerías para desarrollar rich gui para C++

Tags: c++, interfaz-gráfica

Me gustaría diseñar interfaces gráficas actuales.

¿Que librerías me recomiendan para desarrollar interfaces gráficas ricas para C++?

Comment: Este no es un buen lugar para pedir opiniones, creo que el sitio está más orientado a preguntas y respuestas concretas, verificables, objetivas, y las opiniones quedan un poco relegadas a la charla de café. Pero bueno, es mi opinión.

Comment: Como dice @asdasdasd tienes que hacer preguntas objetivas. Di qué caracteristicas necesitas para que te digamos qué libreria cubre esos requisitos. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

QT Creator, para lo cual debes bajar su ide https://www.qt.io/ide/ y te recomiendo la versión community